# What is the location of .bashrc on WSL?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux and am trying to find my terminal's .bashrc file.

Other threads generally indicate one of two locations:

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\{LINUXUSER}\`

or

`C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Lxss\home\USERNAME`

On my machine, the `Local` folder does not contain an `Lxss` subdirectory, so that eliminates the second option, and the `home` folder does not contain anything so that eliminates the first option. Where can I find .bashrc?

Comment: could it be that a `.bashrc` does not exist initially? try to create one and see if it takes effect.

Comment: Where should I create it?

Comment: I addressed why the two solutions there don't work for me in my main post

Comment: Gave that a shot and it didn't work. Makes sense, since "~" is mapped to "/mnt/c/Users/USERNAME", which is the windows filesystem, and bash is likely pulling the .bashrc from somewhere within the Ubuntu filesystem

Comment: I have installed Kali Linux as WSL and I have had the same issue, I have just typed cd ~ and then pwd, my home is set to /home/{USER} then I have found the .bashrc, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently WSL does not create a user by default.

One can be set up as follows

```
$ sudo adduser newuser # new user to play with, creates in /home/newuser like your default
$ sudo cp -aR /home/newuser /mnt/c/Users/<you>
$ sudo echo "echo 'running bashrc'" >> /mnt/c/Users/<you>/newuser/.bashrc
$ sudo usermod -d /mnt/c/Users/<you>/newuser newuser
```

Once you do that, you can edit the .bashrc profile within that user's home directory

That's at `/mnt/c/Users/<you>/newuser/.bashrc` as seen by ubuntu, or `C:\Users\<you>\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\newuser\.bashrc` as seen by Windows

Alternatively, instead of creating a ubuntu user, you could place a `.bash_profile` in `C:\Users\<you>`

See this thread for more info: https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2612

Comment: The answer by @quantumbutterfly is incorrect. The linked thread on github references that people weren't able to get their .bashrc's to run after moving their home directory.

WSL does create a user by default. If it didn't, nothing would work.

Answer (score 1):

@quantumbutterfly's answer is incorrect. The linked thread on github relates to people finding that their `.bashrc` was not run after moving their home directory.

WSL does create a default user. You do that as the last part of the setup.

You should be able to start up a WSL session and create a `.bashrc` in your home directory (~).

If you want to know where that file exists in Windows, just type the following:
`wslpath -aw ~`.

If you are having trouble getting your `.bashrc` sourced after moving your home directory, the `usermod` referenced in quantum's post is likely all you need.

Other workarounds include:

- Create a `.bash_profile` in your home directory and include `source ~/.bashrc` at the end of it.
- Edit the `bash on Ubuntu on Windows` shortcut and add `--rcfile ~/.bashrc` to the end of the command. For example: `C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe ~ --rcfile ~/.bashrc`